# When will Gimp 2.8 come to the software repository?

Tags: gimp

I'm not a novice, I could find a ppa or just compile it but I like to keep my systems tidy. So with that being said, when will Gimp 2.8 come to the software repository?

Also, rather than just getting the answer is there a place on the Ubuntu interwebs some where that I can check the status for other packages as well?

Or is this all done internally at Canonical?

Answer (score 2):

In October 2012, as part of the 12.10 release.

(GIMP 2.8 was released on 3rd May 2012. The 12.10 release is the first after this date. And 12.10 definitely contains version 2.8.)

Answer (score 1):

Exceedingly well managed projects have target dates for versions on their project roadmap.  It appears as of this time that [GIMP](https://launchpad.net/gimp) does not.

Something you can see easily is if the version you want has been packaged in the alpha/beta of the next release.  If it is, you may have some luck in features showing up in backports(although not full version updates...versions freeze for stability reasons).  This is not a definitive answer, but it is what I surmise from my somewhat limited experience in working with proper package management(as opposed to just building what I need).

Related question:

- [How do I get the latest GIMP version available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-gimp-2-8)

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I'm not sure 100% what you are want. You suggest you don't want a ppa, but ask when it'll be in "the software repository"? Well, it's in the launchpad repositories. We're having a discussion [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11913178#post11913178), but essentially, you can install 2.8.0 via ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp (see the web link [here](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp?field.series_filter=precise)). Note that it has the following warning: "CAUTION! This PPA could break your installed OS. There are dependency issues especially for Oneiric (11.10). Only use it if you know what you do! I'm working with others on a stable and reliable solution."

Comment: He explicitly said that he doesn't want PPAs, and "CAUTION! This PPA could break your installed OS..." explains why. He's asking if there will be an update in ubuntu repositories, not 3rd party PPAs.

Comment: I did suspect this, but he/she did ask about "the software repository". Well, ppa's _are_ repositories. I guess he/she means the official Ubuntu release repositories, but was a little unclear. Also, the ppa that I linked says it should be fine if you are running Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. Also, unlike bodhi.zazen's linked ppa, it only includes the additional packages are necessary for gimp 2.8 (i.e. gegl and babl).

Answer (score 1):

Gimp 2.8 will likely be available in the backports repository

You can follow progress on this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/precise-backports/+bug/1002780

In the interim you can install it from this ppa

https://launchpad.net/~laney/+archive/ppa

For information on what backports are see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports